# Why didn't Naruto retain the Gudo dama?

Tags: naruto

If sasuke could retain rinnegan post the fourth great ninja war.. why couldn't Naruto retain the Gudo dama?

Comment: Down vote with out comment?

Comment: Related: [Why does Sasuke still have the Rinnegan?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/18625/why-does-sasuke-still-have-the-rinnegan). It doesn't explain why Naruto didn't keep Gudoudama, but provides a speculative explanation to why Sasuke kept the Rinnegan